# To run macro in each cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to run the goal-seek function in each non-empty cell of a column. but my following code isn't working to do this task. please let me know what I'm doing wrong here.
my code looks like this

```
Sub Test2()

Dim C As Range
Dim i As Long

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("final")
    For Each C In .Range("AH11", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AH").End(xlUp))
        If .Cells(C, "AH") = vbNullString Then GoTo SkipRow
           ActiveCell.GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=ActiveCell.Offset(0, -5).Range( _
    "A1")
SkipRow:
    Next C
End With

End Sub
```

It showing error "If .Cells(C, "AH") = vbNullString"

my task look like this [image]

Image for comment [image]

Comment: This line `If .Cells(C, "AH")` should be `If C`.  `C` refers to the entire cell in a range or collection of cells.

Comment: Try replacing of ActiveCell with c. Otherwise, independent of iteration your code will work only on the active cell...

Comment: Accommodated the above comments, but now while running this macro, the macro goes to a different module code and brings error in all cells of file (Attached screenshot in post)

Comment: Added this "Application.EnableEvents = False" before code but it still goes to function module as shown in the pic, Please help to stop this movement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After changing `ActiveCell` with `c`, as I recommended in my comment, it looks that running the code triggers a UDF function. So, you must use:

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
```

before the code line:

```
For Each C In .Range("AH11", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AH").End(xlUp))
```

and

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

after

```
 Next C
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a correct designation:

```
ActiveCell.GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=ActiveCell.Offset(0, -5).Range("A1")
```

The changing cell means nothing.  If you want to change the cell 5 columns to the left of the cell in column AH.  You would use:

```
C.GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=C.Offset(0,-5)
```

Adding `Range("A1")` makes this invalid.

Comment: Yup changed this but now the problem occurs that it's going to another module that contains a function code as shown in the above-attached picture

Comment: Is there a formula in one of your cells calling that function?  It is not arbitrary and not called in your procedure.